# Sanitizing form data in PHP

Tags: php

Is it possible to sanitize all input sent by one method in PHP by simply doing

```
$var = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST);
```

and then access elements of $var as I would have of $_POST ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think you can call [mysql_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) on an array.

But this would work

```
$cleanData = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_POST);
```

[array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) works by calling the function named in quotes on every element of the array passed to it and returns a new array as the result.

Like [superUntitled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894724/sanitizing-form-data-in-php/894746#894746), I prefer to have a custom function that uses the built-in sanitizing functions as appropriate.  But you could still use a custom function with array_map to achieve the same result.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I did not know about the array_map function, props!

Comment: Could one include in their "escape" function a check-for-array statement, and if it is an array, sanitize all of the elements in the array with the array_map function

Comment: Certainly could. Just use is_array() (and is_object(), if you wanted to catch that too).

Comment: I'm not sure that would work if your escape function had multiple paths for sanitizing a value, like your example below.

Answer (score 1):

As a side note, I would recommend using a function to sanitize your results:

```
function escape($txt) {
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        $txt = stripslashes($txt);

    if (!is_numeric($txt))
        $txt = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($txt) . "'";

   return $txt;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this function will remove html tags from anything you pass to it

```
function strip_html(&$a){
    if(is_array($a)){
        foreach($a as $k=>$v){
            $a[$k]=preg_replace('/<[^<]+?>/','',$v);
        }
    }else{
            $a=preg_replace('/<[^<]+?>/','',$a);
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I find handy is to encapsulate the request data (Post, Get, Cookie etc) in to an Object and then to add a filter method which u can pass an array of function names to. This way you can use it like this:

```
$array = array('trim','mysql_real_escape_string');
$request->filter($array);
```

Body of the method works using a loop an array_map like in Mark's example. I wouldn't run the mysql_real_escape_string over my entire $_POST though, only on the necessary fields ( the ones that are getting queried or inserted )

Answer (score 0):

@Shadow:

Array_Map will work with single dimension array but it wont work with multi-dimension arrays.
So, this will work.

`$cleanData = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_POST);`

but if that $_POST array were to have another array, like this:
`$array = $_POST['myArray']['secondArray'];`

If you have an array such as above, array map will throw an error when you try to run a function that only takes a String as an argument, because it wont be handle to an array when its expecting just a string.

The solution provided on the below page is much more handy, and does it recursively for every element inside the array.

[PHP -Sanitize values of a array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861053/php-sanitize-values-of-a-array/4861080)