# PHP -Sanitize values of a array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sanitization

I have a array, which comes from `$_POST[]` and can have other arrays in it as values, like:

```
array(
 'title' => 'Title',
 'data' => array(
             'hdr' => 'Header'
             'bdy' => 'Body'
           ),
  'foo' => array(1, 23, 65),
  ...
)
```

How can I sanitize all values of this big array?
for eg. apply a `strip_tags()` to values like **Title**, **Header**, **Body**, **1**, **23**, **65** etc ?