# Loop for variable value,

Tags: php, loops

I have a variable generated by `$_POST` called `$quantity`,

What would be the correct way to run a loop based on the value of this variable?

Comment: Depends on the content and what you want to do with it. But possibly [foreach](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) or [for](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php).

Comment: what type of variable is $quantity? what is your end goal?

Comment: In your form do you have `<input name="quantity">` or `<input name="quantity[]">`?

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming that `$quantity` is numerical, you can do this:

```
for ($c = 0; $c < $quantity; $c++) {
  //do whatever
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a for loop (I'm assuming you want to run some code $quantity number of times)

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $quantity; $i++) {
    // 
}
```

Just make sure to [sanitize your POST data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861053/php-sanitize-values-of-a-array/4861211#4861211)