# What is the best way to sanitize POST data?

Tags: wordpress

I am working on a WordPress plugin and need to sanitize the POST data within this function. Would sanitize_text_field() be the best way to go about it? Also what is the proper way to add it to the code below?

```
header( 'Content-Type: application/json' );

        global $wpdb;
$session_id = $_POST['session_id'];
        $procedure_name =  $wpdb->prefix . 'get_geojson_route';
        $gps_locations = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare(
            "CALL {$procedure_name}(%s);", 
            array(
                $session_id
            )
        ));
```

Comment: Sadly, the best way would be not to use Wordpress whatsoever. The other good way would be to start by defining what *sanitize* means to you. This snippet you posted is everything that's bad with Wordpress and practices it encourages.. you're accepting a function name from user input. That lets me stick any kind of crap in. It doesn't even matter if I break something, I can make your site error out and obtain info I'm not supposed to see. And there's the question of whether calling the procedure is the right tool for the job..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To sanatize post data wordpress give function :

$title = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['title'] );

Try this

Comment: This is the solution that I wound up going with.

Comment: what about using `sanitize_post()`? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_post/

Comment: @gillespieza, `sanitize_post()` sanitizes the fields for a WP_Post object.

Comment: @stpetedesign, don't forget to vote up my answer if it helped you! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP you can do as:

```
// it prevents from XSS
$_GET   = filter_input_array(INPUT_GET, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$_POST  = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

This will sanitize your `$_GET` and `$_POST` arrays.

More details: [PHP -Sanitize values of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861053/php-sanitize-values-of-a-array/4861211#4861211)

If you want it in WordPress see this link:

https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/data-sanitization-and-validation-with-wordpress--wp-25536

Comment: This worked well for some of my needs, but when processing the contents of an ACF WYSIWYG editor, it stripped out a lot of the HTML markup. I didn't spend the time to figure out why—this is just a note in case anyone else runs up against this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Using $wpdb->prepare is doing the sanitizing for you

Comment: But you should have it in an array.  Should just be $wpdb->prepare( "CALL {$procedure_name}(%s);", $session_id );

Comment: The [prepare() method](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) also accepts arrays.

Answer (score 1):

If your PHP version is older than 8.1 then you can use

```
$form_data = filter_input_array( INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
```

Else you can use

```
$form_data = filter_input_array( INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS );
```